# Visual Studio Debugging x64 Error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, 64-bit

I've been scratching my head for a while with this issue all day and have done quite a bit of research on stackoverflow as well as the web in general. I can't seem to get my mvc web app to launch properly in visual studio debugger when setting the platform target to x64. I'm running windows 7 64bit.

Here are my steps:

1. Create a new visual studio 2012 project. Selected ASP.NET MVC 4 Web app.
2. Started Debugger. Web app runs fine.
3. Stopped app. Right clicked on The MvcApplication-> Properties -> Build -> set Platform target to x64
4. Top menu -> Build -> Configuration Manager -> Created New active solution platform and set that to x64.
5. Started debugger and get following error:

   ```
    Could not load file or assembly 'MvcApplication2' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

   [BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'MvcApplication2' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +34
      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +16
      System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
      System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
   ```

I read a post on stackoverflow and tried running this regedit but no dice:

1. reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\WebProjects /v Use64BitIISExpress /t REG_DWORD /d 1
2. read from a post that is about 3 yrs old that the debugger doesnt support 64 bit? But not sure how accurate that is anymore

Comment: Any time you see `BadImageFormatException` - this is incompatibility of some components, x64 vs x86. So there we go. One of the components you use is not x64 compatible. And it is true - some things are still not possible in x64.